# A word of phrase for a letter that delivers an "opening charge"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is a good word or phrase for a letter that issues an "opening charge" to a group of people.

In my specific case, I need word for a kind of letter that gives authority and encouragement to a group of people who will author a plan for a large organization.

I'm searching for word that is similar to “invocation”, except that it should *issue* authority rather than appeal to it.

Comment: Is this a _rallying cry_?

Comment: @Barmar - it's more formal than a rallying cry. The speaker is both issuing authority and communicating to the group that they should be bold in executing with that authority.

Comment: 'Rallying cry' sounds good to me, as does a 'call to arms.'

If you owe the informality to the militaristic source domain, and are looking for something closer to 'invocation,' I worry you'll only run into words that sound too religious, along the lines of 'benediction', 'ordination', 'investiture', etc.

Comment: You might call it a *kick-off* letter. I usually think in terms of Kick-off meetings (held to get everyone oriented and aligned at the start of a new project) but it might work for a letter as well.

Comment: a *vote of confidence* could include tacit authorization

Comment: Actually, _authorization_ would be a good choice if the person transferring the power to the newly deputized many has the authority to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst it is not a well used term, it sounds like a letter of **empowerment**.

I think that gives the impression that they have been awarded trust and authorisation within the project, and to some it would also be motivating to have been given 'power'.

From [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/empowerment)

> Empowerment - the giving or delegation of power or authority; authorization